# How do I change the operator font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, unicode-math

The document I am making is using other language (Thai). But the font of the function in the latex is the main font instead of math font (XITS Math). What can I do to change the function font from the main font to the math font?

```
   %% Using Thai font %%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}
\setmainfont[Script=Thai,Scale=1.4,
             ItalicFont={THSarabunNew-Italic.ttf}, 
             BoldFont={THSarabunNew-Bold.ttf},
             BoldItalicFont={THSarabunNew-BoldItalic.ttf} 
            ]{THSarabunNew.ttf}

\newfontfamily{\kanit}{Kanit}[Extension = .ttf]

\setmathfont{XITS Math} % Math Font
```

[image: The font is "TH Sarabun New" which is main font, not math font]

Comment: you should make a small but complete example. If possible use a font that is generally available. And don't use xunicode and xltxtra, they are outdated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you load the `unicode-math` package and do *not* load the `fontspec`, `xunicode` and `xltxtra` packages (at least not explicitly -- `unicode-math` loads `fontspec` automatically)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `unicode-math` sets the operator font (used by `\sin`, `\operatorname`, `\DeclareMathOperator` and so on) to the same font as `\mathrm`, which is the same as the main font of the document.

The simplest way to set `\sin`, `\cos` and such to the XITS text font is

```
\setmathrm{XITS}
```

You could also declare a different font family as your operator font, instead of `\setoperatorfont{\mathrm}`.

If loading XITS by its display name somehow does not work on your installation, you can add this code block above:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[XITS]{
  Ligatures = Common,
  Scale = MatchLowercase,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Extension = .otf}
```

By the way, you have a couple of obsolete packages in your preamble.  You might try something like this:

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\babelprovide[import, main]{thai}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

% The following `\defaultfontfeatures` commands are probably unnecessary.
\defaultfontfeatures[THSarabunNew]{
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Extension = .ttf}
\defaultfontfeatures[XITS]{
  Ligatures = Common,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
  Extension = .otf}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.4]{THSarabunNew}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathrm{XITS}
\setoperatorfont{\mathrm}
```

If you want to mix Thai and English, with XITS as your English font, add the `english` option to the `\documentclass` and the command

```
\babelfont[english]{rm}
          {XITS}
```

On LuaLaTeX, you might or might not need to add the font option `Renderer=HarfBuzz` to your Thai fonts.